# Multiple route paramters with same key in ASP.NET razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a requirement to create multiple quick filters on a table data in `ASP.NET` razor pages application.

For example filters like `Show only my issues`, `Show issues from London location` etc.

I want to manage all these quick filters using a single route parameter `FilterBy` which can make the url like this:

```
baseURL?FilterBy=OnlyMyIssues&FilterBy=LondonLocation
```

Can someone please help me with some way for this?

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to filter, pls

Comment: @D Gogana,the code of `Noah Stahl` can work,you can try to check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397851/pass-array-into-asp-net-core-route-query-string) and check if there is something wrong in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parameter of type string array (`string[]`) to capture multiple values of the same type and query string key. For example:

```
[HttpGet("/GetStuff")]
public IActionResult GetStuff([FromQuery] string[] FilterBy)
{
    // Apply each value in FilterBy, if any
}
```

For this query:

```
GET /getstuff?filterby=foo&filterby=bar
```

You should see this come into the API method:

[image]

If your filters expect different types of values, like booleans and strings, this wouldn't work or be a good design. Better to use dedicated keys like `issueType` and `location` each expecting the appropriate type of value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Noah. I did try using string array but that didn’t seem to work. I will look towards your suggestion to use separate keys. Thanks

Comment: Please add the code you've tried to your question.