# Minimal API - multi-value parameters separated by commas to array of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

I have query parameters such as `/api/items?sizes=m,l,xxl`, meaning they are separated by commas. I want to accept them as array of strings (`[FromQuery] string[] sizes`).

How do I do that? I know how to split the string, the issue is how do I accept `string[]` and let make sure it knows how to split the string?

```cs
string[] sizes = request.Sizes.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Check this link for answers:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397851/pass-array-into-asp-net-core-route-query-string

Comment: @DA, I know. However `?values=this&values=that` is not a solution to my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such transformation is not supported even for MVC binders (it will require query string in one of the following formats: `?sizes[0]=3344&sizes[1]=2222` or `?sizes=24041&sizes=24117`).

You can try using [custom binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-binding):

```cs
public class ArrayParser
{
    public string[] Value { get; init; }

    public static bool TryParse(string? value, out ArrayParser result)
    {
        result = new()
        {
            Value = value?.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) ?? Array.Empty<string>()
        };

        return true;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```cs
app.MapGet("/api/query-arr", (ArrayParser sizes) => sizes.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it going to be `app.MapGet("/api/query-arr", ([FromQuery] ArrayParser? sizes) => sizes?.Value);` for optional query parameter?

Comment: Actually, it appears to be wrong in swagger. `{ "value": [  "string"  ] }`, like it is not an input field that I can input `item1,item2`

Comment: @nop yes. It should have been fixed by [this pr](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/36526) in .NET 7 but it seems that it still does not work.

Comment: @nop see the update, `FromQuery` is not needed, removing it fixes the swagger.

Answer (score 0):

Try using %2c in the URL to replace the commas.

Comment: This is not relevant to the question. I can pass anything in queries. The thing is how do I handle it inside the minimal API, so it accepts `[FromQuery] string[] sizes`