# .NET Core 6.0, SOAPCore endpoint with a string[] request parameters, InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.String[]'

Tags: .net, string, asp.net-core, soap

Trying to send a string[] array as a request parameter in a SOAP GET call. This error keeps popping up at SoapEndpointMiddleware.CS. I'm using SoapCore package in .NET core 6.0 to achieve this.

```
InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.String[]'.
System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
string.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
System.Convert.ChangeType(object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
SoapCore.SoapEndpointMiddleware<T_MESSAGE>.ProcessHttpOperation(HttpContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string methodName)
SoapCore.SoapEndpointMiddleware<T_MESSAGE>.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in SoapEndpointMiddleware.cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Below are my Interface and controller.

IYourService.CS

```
   [ServiceContract]
        public interface IYourService
        {
            [OperationContract]
            string[] ProcessArray(string[] inputArray);
        }
```

YourService.cs

```
public class YourService : IYourService
        {
            public string[] ProcessArray(string[] inputArray)
            {
                // Perform processing on the input array
                List<string> result = new List<string>();
                foreach (string item in inputArray)
                {
                    // Process each item in the array and add the result to the result list
                    string processedItem = "Processed: " + item;
                    result.Add(processedItem);
                }

                // Return the processed array as a result
                return result.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Tried different request URLs

```
http://localhost:5279/yourservice.asmx/ProcessArray?inputArray=300,400
http://localhost:5279/yourservice.asmx/ProcessArray?inputArray=300&inputArray=400
```

Not sure whats missing and any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

can you try this type: http://localhost:5279/yourservice.asmx/ProcessArray?inputArray[]=300&inputArray[]=400

I find it in other answers. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55516012/13548895

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you request use GET method , your request url like this: http://localhost:5279/yourservice.asmx/ProcessArray?inputArray[]=300&inputArray[]=400

Comment: No, it doesnt work, I get this error."Missing value for parameter(s): "ProcessArray", (inputArray)"

Comment: Is your web use .net core controller?

Comment: http://localhost:5279/yourservice.asmx/ProcessArray?inputArray=["300","400"] try this