# MVC routing - Query strings are not applied when default is present

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using this route config :

```
   routes.MapRoute("Default23",
                "{category}",
                new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1 }
            );
```

Here is the controller method :

```
 public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
{
}
```

However , if I use :

```
http://localhost:44123/chess?page=2
```

Then I see that `page=1`  ( not 2 , as I expected):

[image]

BTw - if I change the route to :

```
 routes.MapRoute("Default23",
                "{category}",
                new { controller = "Product", action = "List"  }
            );
```

Then I do see the right value:

[image]

Why is it happening ? all I wanted is to set a default value if I don't set a value
.
Why does setting a default value , prevents reading the query string value ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I route a URL with a querystring in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941967/how-do-i-route-a-url-with-a-querystring-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @Hooman, That is not what OP is asking - you might consider retracting the close vote

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks... I thought [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941967/how-do-i-route-a-url-with-a-querystring-in-asp-net-mvc/6942066#6942066) explains the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain the behavior, the 3rd argument of [MapRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.routecollectionextensions.maproute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_RouteCollectionExtensions_MapRoute_System_Web_Routing_RouteCollection_System_String_System_String_System_Object_) is (my emphasis)

> An object that contains default ***route*** values.

By specifying `new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1 }` you are defining a route value for `page` (even though its not a segment in your url definition) and giving it a default value of `1`.

Now when you navigate to `../chess?page=2` it matches your `Default23` route, and the value of 'chess' is assigned to the `{category}` segment, but nothing is assigned to `page` because there is no segment for `{page}` (its a query string value).

When your `List(string category, int page = 1)` method is executed, the `DefaultModelBinder` evaluates values for binding in the following order

1. Previously bound action parameters, when the action is a child
   action
2. Form values
3. JSON Request body (ajax calls)
4. Route data
5. Query string parameters
6. Posted files

For a GET, 1, 2, 3 and 6 are not applicable, so the `DefaultModelBinder` first evaluates the Route data (`RouteData.Values`) and finds a value of "chess" for `category` (from the url). It also finds a value of "1" for `page` (because you defined a default value for it in the route definition).

At this point you have `category="chess", page=1`.

The `DefaultModelBinder` then evaluates the Query string parameters (`Request.QueryString`) and finds a value of "2" for `page`, but because `page` already has been set, its ignored. By default, the `DefaultModelBinder` binds the first match it finds and ignores all subsequent matches (unless binding to an `IEnumerable` property).

So at this point (the end of the binding process) you still have `category="chess", page=1`.

Comment: So what if I want specify it conditionally via QS and still have a default value ?

Comment: You have already defined a default in the `List()` method (i.e. `int page = 1`) so if you omit `page = 1` from the route definition navigate to `.../chess`, (i.e. no query string) then the value of `page` will be `page=1`